# how to write in bash a function that detect partial names of multiple files in multiple folders?

Tags: bash, loops, detect

I have multiple files like e.g. singletA.dat singletB.dat singletC.dat in multiple folders. Each file presents a common part < singlet > and the extension .dat, and the variable < A B C ...>.
I would like to go through all the folders which contain these files, and independently from the variable A B C ... convert the file name into sing.dat for example. Does in bash exist a function that allows you to detect these partial variables?

Thanks in advance!
tommy

Comment: you could use a glob or regex pattern. However, if you have `singletA.dat` and `singletB.dat` in a single folder, you wont be able to create 2 `sing.dat` files because of conflicting names. Do you want to concatenate the 2 files (or potentially all the files following this naming pattern) into one `sing.dat` ? Is there only 1 `singletX.dat` file per folder ?

Comment: Hi Aserre! Each file is in a different folder... so the conflicting problem is overcome...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use find. For example:

```
find mydir -name "singlet?.dat" -execdir mv {} sing.dat \;
```

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! I tried but it doesn't work using the command like this: find . -name "singlet?.dat" -execdir mv {} sing.dat \...